# php manual increment membership no

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

i've got hundreds of people joining my website and create an membership id for them. i just created a new column in the database called `user_no`.

- whats the mysql query for incrementing the membership no.
- is it possible to start with AE then numbers ie: AE0001, AE0002, .... and it starts with 4 number not AE1, AE2..

mysql query:

```
UPDATE user SET user_no=..??
```

and on PHP side, how do i increment it? if there is a new member join in.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO user (user_no) VALUES(AE'$user_no')");
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use MySQL's auto_increment feature? Why create your own counter? Why append "AE" to the number in the database itself if you can do it when you output the member's id via php? What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: why not use an `auto_increment`ing primary key column?

Comment: You mean want to give every user a specific id?

Comment: @Michael: is it possible to start with four numbers with auto incerement? ie: 0001, 0002?

Comment: @knittl? im using that too. this is for another uniq id :)

Comment: It is, if you specify your auto_increment field as mediumint zerofill. Yet again, that's formatting issue, easily achievable in PHP when you output the data from the db. Same with appending "AE" to the user's number. Store the data in meaningful way so you can manipulate it later, don't manipulate the data immediately, it's not good.

Comment: @boyee: so why not use that number/id for your membership number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an autoincrement field and append AE to it? Autoincrement will be carried out by MySQL so you don't have to worry about it in PHP : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

And to display your user key in the format of `AE0001` you can do

```
$id = 'AE' . str_pad($autoincrementid, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Given that the OP wants the `user_no` field to be the same value as the primary key ID, then this is probably the correct solution. You can also use `sprintf()` to format the string. But be careful of padding it too short -- with the format described above, you'll run out of space after only 10000 users. It sounds like a lot, but if your site is successful it may not take long, and it may be a pain to fix later.

Comment: @Spudley, definitely. I only padded it to 5 because the OP mentioned `AE0001`. You shouldn't be padding it at all once it hits 10k

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everyone else who is saying that you should simply use the MySQL Auto-increment feature. That's what it's there for.

It is possible to write your own, possibly using MySQL's `MAX()` function to find the highest value of a field currently in the table. However unless you're using some very robust transactional code, there is always the danger that this method will result in duplicate records being created when two users create accounts at exactly the same time.

The amount of code required to avoid this is not small, and if you're inexperienced enough not to see the benefits of using Auto-increment then you're unlikely to get it right.

The whole point of Auto-increment is to save you from having to implement all that code every time.

In addition, it is highly recommended for performance reasons to use an integer value for your primary key. Sure, you can display it as `"AE" . $id`, but you should store it as an integer on the database.

Comment: @Spudley: thanks :) i agreed! i just got another uniq id for different purposes.

Comment: @boyee007 -- do you want the `user_no` number to be the same as the record's primary ID with 'AE' in front of it, or is it going to be a completely separate sequence?

Comment: @Spudley: yeah they wud be the same id! the difference is: it starts with 'AE' and 4 numbers. well.. could append AE in php side or which ever way the best. any good solution?

Comment: I made exactly the mistake @Spudley is referring to, and can tell you that it's not fun!

Comment: @boyee - yes, as you say, append using PHP; I'd suggest following @JohnP's solution.

Comment: @Spudley: thanks ;) i can use that code for inserting new id! what about to update? ive got hundreds of user hasnt got 'AE' on 'user_no'. do you know how to update them and increment the 'user_no'?

Comment: @boyee007 - there's no need to store it on the database at all. Just load the main ID field and use PHP to format it as required when you need to display it.